# Is it possible to create Stellarium custom landscape for a small section of horizon?

Tags: stellarium

I would like to create the landscape for Stellarium, which won't include 360degree panorama, but will be restricted i.e. to 30, 50 degrees, and so on. Preferably even a few degrees in order to make my panorama more detailed. I would like to have some very detailed view (with zoom) instead of the standard 360degree overall as usual.
I tried to attach some images with size i.e. 36000x4000Px (covering the horizon only) but they didn't work at all. Later I read that the absolute maximum image size for custom Stellarium landscape is 4096x4096px only.

https://sourceforge.net/p/stellarium/discussion/278769/thread/dd83babc/

I couldn't find anywhere the information about the answer to this question. Everywhere they ay, that the 360-degree panorama is mandatory...

https://astrocamera.net/notebook/Stellarium/index.htm

By seeking the Stellarium user guides I just found something interesting for the landscape.ini file

```
    texturefov = 210
```

With hope, that my panorama will be 210 degrees instead of 360. Unfortunately, it didn't work.

I am asking then - is it possible to have the custom landscape panoramic views in Stellarium other than 360 degrees?

If yes, could you give me some hints on where to find the instruction or what to attach to my landscape.ini file?

If not, could you explain me why?